# Promise Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, promises

Tenho um cenário em que faço vário chamadas Ajax a um WebApi e com o retorno carrego controles de uma aplicação.

Gostaria de criar um método único para efetuar a chamada a API, que receberia um parâmetro com o link, por exemplo 'api/ListaCategorias/'. Neste método gostaria de retornar se ocorreu erro e a lista (json) recuperada.

Criei o seguinte método para a chamada AJAX:

```
        const URL_BASE = "http://10.1.1.121/App/";

    function executaChamadaAPI(URL_API) {
        const URL_SERVICO = URL_BASE + URL_API
        let resultado = {
            erro: "NOK",
            lista: {}
        };
        $.get(URL_SERVICO, function (data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
        })
        .done(function (data) {
               resultado.erro = "OK";
                resultado.lista = $.parseJSON(data);;
        })
       .fail(function () {
                resultado.erro = "NOK";
        })
        .always(function () {
                return resultado;
        });
    }
```

Gostaria de cria uma função para cada controle que tenho de carregar: categorias, usuarios e etc. chamando o método genérico para execução do AJAXexecutaChamadaAPI, passando o caminho, algo assim:

```
        function carregaCategorias{
        var res = executaChamadaAPI('api/ListaCategorias/');

        //Aguardar a execução e retorno do método executaChamadaAPI para posteriormente usar o retorno

        if (res.erro == 'OK'){
            res.lista.forEach(function (o, index) {
                let idCategoria = o.id;
                var html = '<p>' + idCategoria + '</p>';
                $("#result").prepend(html);
            });
        }
        else{
            alert('erro ao executar executaChamadaAPI' );
        }
    }
```

Até fiz da seguinte forma, mas não sei se é a melhor:

```
        const URL_BASE = "http://172.16.106.87/App/";


    function carregaCategorias(res) {
        if (res.erro.toUpperCase() == "OK") {
            res.lista.forEach(function (o, index) {
                let srcImg = URL_BASE + o.PathImagem;
                let idCategoria = o.id;
                var html = '<p>' + idCategoria + '</p>';

                console.log(html);

                $("#result").prepend(html);

            });
        }
        else
            alert('errou rude');
    }

    function executaChamadaAPI(funcRetorno, URL_API) {
        const URL_SERVICO = URL_BASE + URL_API
        console.log('Entrou executaChamadaAPI ' + URL_SERVICO);

        let resultado = {
            erro: "NOK",
            lista: {}
        };

        $.get(URL_SERVICO, function (data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
                resultado.erro = "OK";
                resultado.lista = $.parseJSON(data);;
                console.log("Success executaChamadaAPI  " + resultado.lista.length);

            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.log("error executaChamadaAPI");
                resultado.erro = "NOK";
            })
            .always(function () {
                console.log("Complete executaChamadaAPI ");

               funcRetorno(resultado); //chama uma função de acordo com parâmetro passado
                return resultado;
            });
    }

    executaChamadaAPI(carregaCategorias,'api/ListaCategorias/')
```

Ou talvez o melhor seria que cada função chamasse e tratasse a requisição AJAX?

Comment: Amigo, pelo que vi, o melhor seria cada vez que você chamar a função da requisição tratá-la

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom você pode tirar os tratamentos da função AJAX e retornar apenas a promessa:

```
function executaChamadaAPI(URL_API) {
    const URL_SERVICO = URL_BASE + URL_API
    let resultado = {
        erro: "NOK",
        lista: {}
    };
    return $.get(URL_SERVICO, function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
    });
}
```

Ai você chama a função normalmente e faz o tratamento igual tinha feito antes

```
executaChamadaAPI()
.done(function (data) {
           resultado.erro = "OK";
            resultado.lista = $.parseJSON(data);;
    })
   .fail(function () {
            resultado.erro = "NOK";
    })
    .always(function () {
            return resultado;
    });
```